# How do I resolve this torch ImportError on macOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, jupyter, torch

I'm trying to `import torch` in my .ipynb file, but I'm getting the following error:

```
ImportError: Failed to load PyTorch C extensions:
    It appears that PyTorch has loaded the `torch/_C` folder
    of the PyTorch repository rather than the C extensions which
    are expected in the `torch._C` namespace. This can occur when
    using the `install` workflow. e.g.
        $ python setup.py install && python -c "import torch"

    This error can generally be solved using the `develop` workflow
        $ python setup.py develop && python -c "import torch"  # This should succeed
    or by running Python from a different directory.
```

I'm using macOS Ventura 13.4.1 with graphics Intel Iris Plus Graphics 1536 MB. I'm running the code through DataSpell, python version 3.9.6.

I've read somewhere that this might have something to do with me not having an NVIDIA GPU, but nothing that actually told me how to fix my issue. Really hoping to get some help! Thanks!

Comment: If you are using MacOS then you can only use the CPU version of torch following here: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/.  How did you install torch on your Mac?